# Indexing form the end of a generator

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

Say I have a generator in Python and I want to iterate over everything in it except the first 10 iterations and the last 10 iterations. itertools.islice supports the first part of this slicing operation, but not the second. Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only is there not a simple way, there is not a way at all, if you want to allow any generator (or any iterable).  In general, there is no way to know when you are 10 items from the end of a generator, or even whether the generator has an end.  Generators only give you one item at a time, and tell you nothing about how many items are "left".  You would have to iterate through the entire generator, keeping a temporary cache of the most recent 10 items, and then yield those when (or if!) the generator terminates.

Note the "or if".  A generator need not be finite.  For an infinite generator, there is no such thing as the "last" 10 elements.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might do the job. EDIT: Added use of deque as per comments.

```
from collections import deque
def generator():
    for i in ['ignore'] * 10 + ['yield this'] * 10 + ['ignore'] * 10:
        yield i


def func(mygenerator):
    cache = deque()
    for i, item in enumerate(mygenerator()):
        if i < 10:
            continue
        cache.appendleft(item)
        if len(cache) > 10:
            yield cache.pop()

for i in func(generator):
    print i
```

Comment: I was thinking about a similar solution. If speed matters, you might have to use a `Queue` object or so for the cache. As far as I understand, lists are not optimized for repeatedly inserting from the beginning.

Comment: Use `collections.deque`. It's designed to allow fast access to values at each end, so both your `insert` (as `pushleft`) and `pop` calls will be fast. It's the data structure that underlies `queue.Queue` (which is for communication between threads).

Comment: It's somewhat a shame that `collections.deque` can't be overridden to override `popleft` (which one would guess would be called to discard elements) to yield an element, then one could use it with the `maxlen` parameter... Then you'd have something like `mydeque(islice(iterable, None, 10), 10)`